# Why do we say "as it were"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

In English we often add "as it were" to indicate that a phrase is not to be taken literally; for example:

> He's flown from the nest, as it were.

... would indicate that a boy has left his parent's house, via the "flown from the nest" idiom.  But, why does "as it were" clarify that this is an idiom?

Comment: Judging from [J.R.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/63590/12543)'s answer it can be read as "*as if [his parent's house] (it) was [a nest]*".

Comment: @bitmask or indeed "as if the house *were* a nest."

Comment: Idiom? More like a metaphore...

Comment: @phoog: I known you shouldn't ask sub-questions in comments; But isn't the house here 3rd person singular? So I thought I'd to use "was" instead of "were".

Comment: @bitmask: I've already given you the answer - that it's the subjunctive mood.

Comment: @bitmask as in, "if I were king..."

Comment: A phrase by uppity writers to accord them some sort of literary legitmacy--they think. In fact, the highfalutin parenthetical expression is meaningless, as it were.

Comment: I'd like to see an answer that explains how and why the "if" got dropped.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Interesting thought: that *as it were* might be an idiom, used to emphasize that something else in the sentence is also an idiom.

Merriam-Webster's online dictionary defines *[as it were](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as+it+were)* thusly:

> **as it were**   :
>   *as if it were so; in a manner of speaking*

[Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/as%20it%20were) lists these synonyms:

> - *so to speak*
> - *in a way*
> - *in a manner of speaking*

Answer (score 22):

It's an example of [English subjunctive mood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive) (one of the irrealis moods).

This particular example is a set phrase (relic from an older form of the language where it was much more common) where subjunctive needs to be employed.

Comment: +1 for the only answer to mention subjunctive mood

Answer (score 9):

It is used, in the words of the Oxford English Dictionary, ‘as a parenthetic phrase . . . to indicate that a word or statement is perhaps not formally exact though practically right’. It’s very old, being first recorded around 1200.

Answer (score 2):

"As it were..." indicates that the mood of the sentence or clause is subjunctive, viz. a counter-factual or improbable hypothetical is being provisionally taken as true in the sentence.

Answer (score -5):

It is a filler phrase that means nothing in modern English. It makes one look less than intelligent because it sounds like you are "trying" to sound smart - which makes one look ______.